# Can I use native primitive types in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

The same as C#, int is an alias for System::Int32, which is an CLR type. Is there a way I can use a native "int", which means int in standard c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/CLI primitive types have dual identity.  The type keywords match *both* the native C++ type and the CLR type, depending on context.  And variables with native type sort of inherit the methods available on the CLR type, like `ToString`.

I think this blog article explaining the relationship between native and managed types is pretty helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/branbray/archive/2005/07/20/441099.aspx

Comment: But I am confused. If the /clr compiler switch in on. I can define int number = 100, and call number .ToString() because it is System::Int32. If the /clr switch is off, then number must not be System::Int32. So, with /clr on and off, the compiler treats the int type differently?

Comment: @Ryan: If you aren't using `/clr`, then you aren't using C++/CLI, and my answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer does not answer the OP's question.

If the `/clr` compiler switch is on, then the `int` keyword means `System::Int32`, it is not native.
If the `/clr` compiler switch is off, then the `int` keyword means native C/C++ `int`, it is not managed.

Using `System::Int32` implies a significant performance penalty over native `int` (you can measure it).

You can turn off the `/clr` compiler switch per `.cpp` file. It is not a Project option, it is a translation unit (.cpp file) option.
Right click on the file, then properties, etc...

So, you can write some native code in a `.cpp` file (compiled with `/clr` off).
Then you can write managed code in another file (compiled with `/clr` on) and invoke the native code.

Answer (score -1):

They're the same thing, go ahead and use `int` everywhere you want the native type.